# Distributing random value between X number of recipients

Tags: python

I'm looking for a simple code I could use in Python that allows me to randomly split a certain value into a set of numbers, the sum of which is equal to initial value.

For example:

I have 50 points and I want to randomly (not evenly) distribute them between seven recipients, like 15, 10, 7, 3, 8, 2, 5.

I was unable to find anything on Google probably due to using wrong terminology.I'm completely new to this kind of stuff so please talk to me like you would to a  4 year old. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While you might get an answer to this, this site is for explicit programming questions and not for asking others to code for you.

Comment: my apologies, I'll delete my post.

Comment: Also a question: Should it in your example be possible, that the first recipient gets 50 points and the rest zero?

Comment: Don't get demotivated by the downvotes! It is always okay to ask, but if you can't provide at least some code to show you tried, it's best to first work through some Tutorials

Comment: No, all recipients should get at least 1 point.

Comment: A quick search on google for ´randomly split a certain value into a set of numbers´ came up with some helpful links.

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
def partition(x,num_rec):
      if(x<num_rec):
          print('please provide a number of recipient inferior to the number')
          return 0
      res = []
      for i in range(num_rec-1):
          j = random.randint(1,x-(num_rec-i))
          res.append(j)
          x = x-j
      res.append(x)
      return np.random.permutation(res)
```

and if you test:

```
for i in range(10):
    r = partition(50,7)
    print(sum(r),r)

>>> 50 [16  4  2  1 24  1  2]
>>> 50 [ 2  1  6 17  1  2 21]
>>> 50 [ 1  5  5  8  2  2 27]
>>> 50 [36  2  2  1  1  7  1]
>>> 50 [ 3  2 18  1  3  1 22]
>>> 50 [ 3 17  6  2  4  4 14]
>>> 50 [ 1 12 12  3  2 17  3]
>>> 50 [ 3 34  4  1  1  1  6]
>>> 50 [ 2  2  3  2 26  9  6]
>>> 50 [ 3  2  1  2 16  1 25]
```

As pointed out, the list tend to be sorted so you can add a random permutation to avoid this. (code updated above)

an other way to do it is to create a list and to fill it randomly.
with this method you won't get the imbalance issue.

```
def partition(x,num_rec):
      res = [1]*num_rec
      for i in range(x-num_rec):
            res[random.randint(0,num_rec-1)] +=1
      return res

>>> 50 [6, 6, 10, 7, 6, 6, 9]
>>> 50 [9, 6, 7, 7, 7, 5, 9]
>>> 50 [8, 7, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5]
>>> 50 [6, 3, 14, 7, 6, 3, 11]
>>> 50 [12, 5, 12, 4, 4, 6, 7]
>>> 50 [6, 7, 9, 5, 6, 7, 10]
>>> 50 [8, 6, 6, 5, 6, 5, 14]
>>> 50 [4, 10, 6, 9, 7, 9, 5]
>>> 50 [8, 4, 9, 5, 8, 9, 7]
>>> 50 [9, 10, 7, 7, 6, 4, 7]
```

this will converge toward a more evenly distribution.

Comment: This kind of algorithm has a strong bias to give the first recipient the most points

Comment: @user8408080 updated, the imbalance issue is solve by solution 2 (evenly) and sol1 (shuffling)

Comment: Thank You, Alexis. Would this look correct when I input the numbers?

 def partition(50,7):
      res = [1]*7
      for i in range(50-7):
            res[random.randint(0,7-1)] +=1
      return res

Comment: I'm getting SyntaxError: invalid syntax on the first line, number 50.

 `>>> def partition(50,7):`

Comment: you can't define a function with numbers like that, use my function and then call it with partition(50,7)

Comment: @Animenautas then accept the answer to close the question please